# Is a Chinese passport holder eligible for South Korea 30-day visa exemption?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, south-korea

I have a Chinese passport with a USA H1B visa, originally scheduled for a flight from NKG (Nanjing) to SFO via ICN on the same day. Asiana Airlines rescheduled my first leg exactly 24 hours earlier so I will have an entire day before my second leg. I don't mind staying in Korea for one night to do some light sightseeing, but do I qualify for the 30-day visa exemption rule?

Most websites say this is allowed (for example this [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=cn&destination=us&transit=kr) one) but [this KETA](https://www.ketasouthkorea.com/transit-visa-south-korea) one lists China under the not eligible countries. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The KETA has nothing to do with the 30-day exemption. It's the Korean equivalent of the ESTA and brethren, an authorization to fly to the country that issues it, for people who have visa-free access. You do not have visa-free access, hence you are not eligible to a KETA. But as I said, it's nothing to do with the visa exemption scheme.

That scheme is for non visa-exempt nationals who are in transit through South Korea. Like you. Your flights match the conditions. And you need to hold a physical visa or a residence permit issued by (in your case) the US. So supposing your H1B is a physical visa in your passport, you are good to go. Enjoy Seoul, albeit briefly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be eligible for the 30-day visa exemption since your flights match the transit conditions and you have a valid US H1B visa in your passport.

I'd say go ahead and enjoy that day in Seoul - even just a brief overnight stay could allow you to see a few top sights. It may help to book a local guide. That way you can hit some top spots efficiently with an expert. A guide could take you to major attractions like Gyeongbokgung Palace and Insa-dong, plus recommend somewhere good for a meal.

Found this one that offers private tours in Seoul https://gowithguide.com/korea/seoul/guides Might be a good way to make the most of your short time!

Have fun exploring and safe travels!